# AVQueuePlayer equivalent on android

Tags: android, iphone, ios

In iPhone, we can use `AVQueuePlayer`, `AVAsset`, and `AVPlayerItem` if we want to play a list of movies sequentially. It is very convenient over `MPMediaPlayer` and `MPMediaPlayerController` in iPhone. From, [apple documentation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
AVQueuePlayer is a subclass of AVPlayer you use to play a number 
of items in sequence.
```

So, my question is, is there anything like that in android which we can use instead of `MediaPlayer` and `VideoView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, there is no automatic way of playing sounds in sequence (at least not a "built-in" one).  If you need to start playback of the second sound when the first one finishes, you can use method

```
public void setOnCompletionListener (MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listener)
```

of the `MediaPlayer` to start the second playback when the first one is finished.  Something like this:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uriOfFirstSound);
player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setDataSource(context, uriOfNextSound);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
));
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

Naturally, if you have more than two sounds, you can do this in a loop.

Comment: I do know about `OnCompletionListener` and I am using it now. But, if we have something like `AVQueuePlayer`, that would make things a lot easier. ie., I don't have to bother about video completion, setting new path, starting it, etc., All I need to do was to put items to the queue, and everything else will be taken care of by the player `AVQueuePlayer`

Comment: @Jomoos agree, but, unfortunately, Android doesn't provide one out-of-the-box.  There's nothing preventing you from creating one.  Seems quite simple to me.